# Write data into oracle database in r using loop

Tags: r

I was able to make a market basket analysis in `r` on the database.
I've finished my analysis and i want to write results into oracle database row by row. I've tried this

```
sonuclar<-inspect(basket_rules[1:5])
mode(sonuclar)
[1] "list"
class(sonuclar)
[1] "data.frame"
for(row in 1:nrow(sonuclar)) {`dbGetQuery(jdbcConnection,paste0("insert into market_basket_analysis (lhs,rhs,support,confidence,lift)
values ('",sonuclar$lhs[row],"','",sonuclar$rhs[row],"','",sonuclar$support[row],"','",sonuclar$confidence[row],"','",sonuclar$lift[row],"')"))}`
```

but it writes for only one row , it doesn't work for other loop iteration steps and it returns an error message :

```
`Error in .verify.JDBC.result(md, "Unable to retrieve JDBC result set meta data for ",  : 
  Unable to retrieve JDBC result set meta data for insert into market_basket_analysis (lhs,rhs,support,confidence,lift) values ('{SPRITE GAZOZ1,5L}','{COCACOLA # 1,5LT}','0.00395004588437138','0.439024390243902','1.99010097534508') in dbSendQuery (ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement
)`
```

even though it gives an error , it inserted

```
{SPRITE GAZOZ1,5L},{COCACOLA # 1,5LT},'0.00395043993535644','0.439024390243902','1.98990246549237'
```

this is the first row.

I have not found meaningful information in the internet although i have searched a lot for over a week ; have any idea to solution about this error. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me it was also a bit surprising that it did not work, but yes, it is actually fairly easy to reproduce with the code you provide. Until the moment, whenever I had to do something similar I've used `dbWriteTable`, I wonder if you can't do it for whatever the reason.

Anyway, if you really need or want to insert in a loop, you should use bind variables. Your loop would look like this,

```
for(row in 1:nrow(sonuclar)) {
 inss <-  paste0("insert into temp (lhs,rhs,support,confidence,lift) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)")
 dbSendUpdate(con, inss, list=as.list(sonuclar[row, ]))
}
```

(Note that my connection is called `con` and the table `temp`, instead of your names...) Just for reference, I've defined your data.frame like this,

```
sonuclar <- data.frame(matrix(c('{SPRITE GAZOZ1,5L}','{COCACOLA # 1,5LT}',0.00395004588437138,0.439024390243902,1.99010097534508,
                                '{SPRITE GAZOZ1,5L}','{COCACOLA # 1,5LT}',0.00395043993535644,0.439024390243902,1.98990246549237),
                              nrow=2, ncol=5, byrow=TRUE))
colnames(sonuclar) <- c('lhs','rhs','support','confidence','lift')
```

and in the table I've used `varchar(20)` for `lhs` and `rhs`, and `number(10,4)` for the other columns.

A final note, I don't know how big is your loop, but it would be better if you disabled your `autocommit` (by default a TRUE),

```
.jcall(con@jc, "Z", "getAutoCommit")
[1] TRUE
.jcall(con@jc, "V", "setAutoCommit", FALSE)
```

But then you need to commit outside of your loop, just

```
dbCommit(con)
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: yes it really helps , thanks a lot for that . at first i had used [tag:dbWriteTable] but it had returned similar error.

Comment: Thank you, glad it was useful. For me it worked fine with the simple example dataframe when using `dbWriteTable`... but anyway it is true that `dbWriteTable` has some disadvantages, does not allow you full control.